# MVC3 using Open Office to convert Docx to PDF Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Newbie to site and MVC/.net web development.

I have searched hi and low and although there are some threads about this issue, I cannot seem to get a solution/direct answer ... hopefully someone here can assist.

I am using VS2010/MVC3/C#/.Net4/IIS7 to develop an internet app. making use of Open Office 3.4.1 to create PDF's from Docx documents.

I used this approach: http://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/

All works fine on my local development machine, however as soon as I publish on the test server ... the bootstrap call (line 10) does not return (simply hangs for lack of better description)

Hopefully someone here can help.

Thanks, Eugene

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have installed **Open Office** on your development machine. You have to do the same on your web server making sure you're using the same Open Office version.

Your application must reference these assemblies:

1. cli_basetypes.dll
2. cli_cppuhelper.dll
3. cli_oootypes.dll
4. cli_ure.dll
5. cli_uretypes.dll

and they all have to be set "**Copy Local**" to **false**.
You won't deploy these dlls cause they're going to be loaded from the **GAC**.

If your IIS is running on a x64 OS you might need to:
 **"Enable 32-Bit Applications"** = **True**

This [article](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/net-working-with-openoffice-3/) might help you.
If you want to dig [deeper](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/CLI/CLI_Language_Binding).

Comment: Yes to all the questions ... will check out the links ... thanks

Comment: Already read and tried the article's approach = no different ... was hoping someone can help b4 I need to spend more time digging deeper into the 2nd link